# convert xml file to text file using XSLT

Tags: xml, file, xslt, text

I want to transfer this xml file (xy.xml) below to text file using xslt.
The text file should only take the value of tag initialValue 
for exmaple this value of inintialvalue should be printed in new text file zx.txt (pressure or pain in the sinuses and nose, in the ears and teeth)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<specificationSet xmlns="http://www.yawlfoundation.org/yawlschema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="4.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.yawlfoundation.org/yawlschema http://www.yawlfoundation.org/yawlschema/YAWL_Schema4.0.xsd">
  <specification uri="sinusitis">
    <documentation>No description provided</documentation>
    <metaData>
      <creator>k_k10</creator>
      <description>No description provided</description>
      <coverage>4.1.739</coverage>
      <version>0.4</version>
      <persistent>false</persistent>
      <identifier>UID_b698b345-b6ce-45a5-8e12-576ed2861094</identifier>
    </metaData>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
    <decomposition id="Net" isRootNet="true" xsi:type="NetFactsType">
      <localVariable>
        <index>0</index>
        <name>symptom1</name>
        <type>string</type>
        <namespace>http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema</namespace>
        <initialValue>facial tenderness and nasal congestion</initialValue>
      </localVariable>
      <localVariable>
        <index>1</index>
        <name>symptom2</name>
        <type>string</type>
        <namespace>http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema</namespace>
        <initialValue>pressure or pain in the sinuses and nose, in the ears and teeth</initialValue>
      </localVariable>
      <localVariable>
        <index>2</index>
        <name>symptom3</name>
        <type>string</type>
        <namespace>http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema</namespace>
        <initialValue>cloudy discolored nasal or postnasal drainage. alos, nose arritation</initialValue>
      </localVariable>
```

Comment: What have you tried? What issues are you getting? Please check [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:a="http://www.yawlfoundation.org/yawlschema"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>        

    <xsl:template match="/">
       <xsl:result-document href="zx.txt">
           <xsl:value-of select="//a:initialValue" separator="&#xA;"/>
       </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
facial tenderness and nasal congestion
pressure or pain in the sinuses and nose, in the ears and teeth
cloudy discolored nasal or postnasal drainage. alos, nose arritation
```

Comment: do i need to link xy.xml file to xslt file??

Comment: @KhalidKhawaji, Yes

Comment: how to do linkage

Comment: I have multiple intialvalues how can i get all of them

Comment: how do i write the output to text file

Comment: @KhalidKhawaji, for linking check [How to link XML with XSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40949049/create-link-to-xml-with-xsl-stylesheet).

Comment: last question please how can i get file.txt

Comment: Or use an XSLT processor like Saxon (https://www.saxonica.com/html/welcome/welcome.html). Saxon runs from the command line, the command you use specifies the XSLT and the XML file it should process. (https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/using-xsl/commandline/)